# ‘to this end’ or ‘toward this end’ or ‘towards this end’?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

To say *‘in order to achieve this goal’*, should I use...?

- *to this end*
- *toward this end*
- *towards this end*

Which of these would be correct, and which is used most often?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"To this end" would be the correct usage. See [here](http://fraze.it/n_search.jsp?q=%22to%20this%20end%22&l=0&t=0&ffo=false&findid=-1&ff=) for a list of examples.

[This ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to%20this%20end%2C%20toward%20this%20end%2C%20towards%20this%20end&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cto%20this%20end%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctoward%20this%20end%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctowards%20this%20end%3B%2Cc0) proves that "to this end" is the more common usage.

Comment: I could also find examples for the other two phrase. Does this mean that they are also correct?

Answer (score 0):

To this purpose is another good expression to use as well.

To this purpose, an automated parameters extraction procedure is proposed.